# 'User' object has no attribute '__getitem__' error

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class StudentUsername(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
```

When I try to add a user and student to this table using default Django Admin interface, I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Kindly help.

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  432.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in inner
  371.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view
  1133.                 self.log_addition(request, new_object)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in log_addition
  600.             action_flag=ADDITION
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\models.py" in log_action
  19.         e = self.model(None, None, user_id, content_type_id, smart_text(object_id), object_repr[:200], action_flag, change_message)

Exception Type: TypeError at /backoffice/students/studentusername/add/
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Paste the error's traceback.

Comment: Which version of Django (since the User model has changed a bit), and what is User here (eg, show the import statement)?

Comment: I am using Django 1.6.5. The import statement is "from django.contrib.auth.models import User"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that you have defined a `__unicode__` method on StudentUsername that is returning either a User or a Student object - that is, `self.user` or `self.student` - rather than actual unicode. So when Django tries to slice it, it gets this error.

Ensure that your unicode method actually returns unicode text.